# Get the id's of previous and next projects only if they don't contain ".isotope-hidden"

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-isotope

Im struggling to build a proper project filter with jquery isotope. I only want to get the id's of previous and next projects if they are not hidden by the 'isotope-hidden' class. How can I do this?

```
// Get the id's of previous and next projects
if ( $prev.length !== 0 && $next.length !== 0 ) {
    prev_item_id = $prev.find('.project-link').attr( "data-post_id" );
    next_item_id = $next.find('.project-link').attr( "data-post_id" );
}
else if ( $prev.length !== 0 ) {
    prev_item_id = $prev.find('.project-link').attr( "data-post_id" );
}
else if ( $next.length !== 0 ) {
    next_item_id = $next.find('.project-link').attr( "data-post_id" );
}
```

---

the problem is I need to put the logic in here somewhere. But I can't work out how to adapt this to exclude projects hidden by the isotope-hidden class. Is it something like this?

```
var post_id = $( this ).attr( "data-post_id" );
        current_post_id = post_id;

        var nonce = $( this ).attr( "data-nonce" );
 var $allitems = $('.project-link').not('isotope-hidden');
        var $prev = $allitems.[data-post_id="' + post_id + '"]' .parent().parent().prev('.portfolio-item');
        var $next = $allitems.[data-post_id="' + post_id + '"]' .parent().parent().next('.portfolio-item');
```

Any help much appreciated, Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
function getHiddenIds($element) {
    return $('.project-link:not(.isotope-hidden)', $element).data('post_id');
}
var prev_item_id = getHiddenIds($prev);
var next_item_id = getHiddenIds($next);
```

*References*:

- `:not()`: http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/
- `.data()`: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you want.  Just use [not()](http://api.jquery.com/not/)

```
$prev.find('.project-link').not('.isotope-hidden').attr( "data-post_id" );
$next.find('.project-link').not('.isotope-hidden').attr( "data-post_id" );
```

Comment: Thanks for quick reply but this isn't returning project links that aren't hidden. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply store all items before assigning click events

```
$items = $('.item'); // to reference methods on all .item divs later
```

and then inside your Isotope logic find the ones with the .isotope-hidden class applied

```
$items.find('.isotope-hidden').somemethod('someclass'); // do some stuff with them
```

If you have a fiddle, it would be easier to understand what logic you're after as a whole.